# Mole System.Random class

Tags: c#, random, moles, pex

I have the following method to test :

```
public float coverageJump(bool a)
{
    int c = 0;
first:
    c++;
    Random random = new Random();
    float result = random.Next(0, 100);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    if(result < 50)
        goto first;
    if (result == 50)
        goto end;

    if (a)
        goto end;
    else
        goto first;

end:
    return c;
}
```

Pex suggest me to use Random.Next moled and its create :

**PexMethod :**

```
[PexMethod]
public float coverageJump([PexAssumeUnderTest]ClassMethod target, bool a)
{
    float result = target.coverageJump(a);
    return result;
    // TODO: add assertions to method ClassMethodTest.coverageJump(ClassMethod, Boolean)
}
```

**Parametrized Unit Test**

```
[TestMethod]
[PexGeneratedBy(typeof(ClassMethodTest))]
[PexRaisedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void coverageJumpThrowsNullReferenceException489()
{
    float f;
    RandomPreparation.Prepare();
    ClassMethod s0 = new ClassMethod();
    f = this.coverageJump(s0, false);
}
```

And the prepare method to mock Random Class:

```
[PexPreparationMethod(typeof(Random))]
public static void Prepare()
{
    MRandom.BehaveAsCurrent();
}
```

I developed the prepare method to mock Random class

```
MRandom.BehaveAsCurrent();
MRandom mr = new MRandom()
{
    NextInt32Int32 = (b, c) => { return 1; },
    Sample = () => { return 1; },
    InternalSample = () => { return 1; }
};

MRandom.Constructor = (a) => 
{
    // a.Next = (b, c) => { return 1; };
};

MRandom.Behavior = mr.InstanceBehavior;
```

But I get the following **NULL Exception** :

```
--- Description
failing test: NullReferenceException, Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.

float f;
RandomPreparation.Prepare();
ClassMethod s0 = new ClassMethod();
f = this.coverageJump(s0, false);


[TestMethod]
[PexGeneratedBy(typeof(ClassMethodTest))]
[PexRaisedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void coverageJumpThrowsNullReferenceException387()
{
    float f;
    RandomPreparation.Prepare();
    ClassMethod s0 = new ClassMethod();
    f = this.coverageJump(s0, false);
}
```

---

Exception details

```
System.NullReferenceException: Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.      at System.Int32 System.Random.InternalSample() 
      at System.Double System.Random.Sample() 
      at System.Int32 System.Random.Next(System.Int32 minValue, System.Int32 maxValue) 
    D:\Sviluppo\UNI\TesiTirocinio\src\TutorialsMolePex\BenchMarkTesterTool\BenchMarkTesterToolLib\ClassMethod.cs(154): at System.Single BenchMarkTesterToolLib.ClassMethod.coverageJump(System.Boolean a) 
    D:\Sviluppo\UNI\TesiTirocinio\src\TutorialsMolePex\BenchMarkTesterTool\BenchMarkTesterToolLib.Tests\ClassMethodTest.cs(27): at System.Single BenchMarkTesterToolLib.ClassMethodTest.coverageJump(BenchMarkTesterToolLib.ClassMethod target, System.Boolean a)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What's the actual question? And is this homework?

Comment: Hi Pickypg , I want to do a thesis about Pex and Moles, so I'm studing the behavior of pex . The quesion is : "How can I mole Rando class to pass always the "1" when the method Random.Next is called by the Unit Test ?" Thanks a lots, Best regards.

Comment: You should look at Microsoft's Fakes instead of Moles. Moles is deprecated, and Fakes is its substitution (by the same team at MS Research, by the way). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution to my problem in the Prepare Method:

**Prepare()**:

```
    [PexPreparationMethod(typeof(Random))]
    public static void Prepare()
    {
        MRandom.Behavior = MoleBehaviors.Fallthrough;
        MRandom.AllInstances.NextInt32Int32 = (r, a, b) => { return 50; };
    }
```

I think to use another implementation

```
        var fake = new SRandom { CallBase = true };
        var mole = new MRandom(fake)
        {
            NextInt32Int32 = (a, b) => { return 1;  }
        };
        MRandom.BehaveAsCurrent();
```

but not work. For a little time I think that I cannot mock Random's method Next because in Mole Manual Reference is reported : 
*.. the Moles framework to create mole types, which take advantage of runtime instrumentation. They are useful when dealing with APIs with static methods, sealed types, or **nonvirtual methods** ..*

and  Random's method Next is:

```
        public virtual int Next(
            int minValue,
            int maxValue
        )
```

Could someone give me an explanation because my "Prepare" method work ?

Thanks a lot, best regards.